# Is there a way to query more than 2,000 Intents in Dialogflow CX? I.e. Setting up parallel flows?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

I'm creating an agent with more than 2,000 intents. Basically a FAQ bot that can answer thousands of questions.

In Dialogflow ES, there was the concept of MegaAgents and SubAgent. The maximum number of intent for a SubAgent was 2,000. Using a MegaAgent, I could put together up to 20 Sub Agents (total 20,000 intents). When the user queries the bot, each intent is weighted differently.

Now in Dialogflow CX, although the entire agent has a maximum 10,000 intents, each flow has a 2,000 limit. I can't figure out a way to design the bot to have multiple "parallel" flows where there is equal weighting given to each flow.

The only way is string together multiple flows in sequence, and use a Fallback to transition from one flow to another. However, this doesn't put equal query weighting on my many thousand intents.

Any suggestions?